# Iterate children TemplateRefs from TemplateRef

Tags: angular, ng-template

Is it possible to iterate TemplateRefs from TemplateRef?

```
<my-component [template]="template"></my-component>
<ng-template #template>
    <ng-template *ngFor="let field of fields">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I want to do something like this.

```
@Input() template: TemplateRef<any>
```

and into the template something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let x of template">
    <h1>Bla bla bla</h1>
    <div *ngTemplateOutlet="x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect a typo in the question. The tags inside the outer `<ng-template>` doesn't match. The opening tag is `<ng-template>` whereas the closing tag is `</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this should probably work.

Parent:

```
@ViewChildren("template") templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;


<ng-template #template *ngFor="let field of fields">
        bla bla bla
</ng-template>
```

Child:

```
@Input() templates: TemplateRef<any>[];

<div *ngFor="let x of templates">
    <h1>Bla bla bla</h1>
    <div *ngTemplateOutlet="x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So with anchor I can only do ViewChild... Not ViewChildren? Right?

Comment: ViewChildren doesn't have {static: boolean} property. It is only for ViewChild

Comment: my bad, of course you are right, I have removed it. Did you manage to make it work in the end?

Comment: Yes, it works with ViewChildren and I have reached the conclusion that there is no way to do that from the template. Anchor (#) is only for ViewChild

Comment: yes, I can't think of a way to do it without a ViewChildren variable. I'm glad to have been of help, have a good day!